# Creating a Folder in C# - Windows thinks its both a file and folder

Tags: c#, .net, window, system.io.directory

I’m having a random issue where windows thinks a folder is actually a file and folder.  It happens on random machines and I’m not able to duplicate it.  I’m running the .NET Directory.CreateDirectory method.

I’m basically running this code:

```
string directoryToCreate = folderPath + @"\" + directoryName + @"\";
 if (Directory.Exists(directoryToCreate ) == false)
         Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToCreate);
```

After the directory is created, I’ll copy down a bunch of files to it.

The folder/file shows up in explorer as a “File” type, but you’re not able to create another file or folder with the same name.  I’ve tried code with and without the backslash and it doesn’t make a difference

This is called right after the directory is created:

```
    private static void ProcessDirectoryForUpdating(string pNetworkFolder, string pLocalFolder)
    {
        DirectoryInfo networkFolder = new DirectoryInfo(pNetworkFolder);
        DirectoryInfo localFolder = new DirectoryInfo(pLocalFolder);

        try
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo tmpNetworkFolder in networkFolder.GetDirectories())
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFolder.Name) == false)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFolder.Name);

                ProcessDirectoryForUpdating(tmpNetworkFolder.FullName, localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFolder.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tracer.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, "ProcessDirectoryForUpdating:  Error processing directory " + pNetworkFolder + "  " + ex.Message);
        }

        foreach (FileInfo tmpNetworkFile in networkFolder.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFile.Name) == false)
                    tmpNetworkFile.CopyTo(localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFile.Name, true);
                else if (tmpNetworkFile.LastWriteTime > (new DirectoryInfo(localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFile.Name).LastWriteTime))
                    tmpNetworkFile.CopyTo(localFolder.FullName + @"\" + tmpNetworkFile.Name, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tracer.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, "ProcessDirectoryForUpdating:  Error processing file " + tmpNetworkFile.FullName + "  " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get at which statement?

Comment: Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
Stack:
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(System.String, System.String, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(System.String, Boolean)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.String)
at CasewareLauncher.MainLine.UpdateFilesFolders()
at CasewareLauncher.MainLine.MainStart()
at CasewareLauncher.Program.Main()

Comment: It looks like it creates the folder/file the first time and when the code runs again (a day later) it fails on the createdirectory.  I cannot duplicate the issue.

Comment: could you please show the code that creates file as well?

Comment: updated with the other code